# How to set the Bearer token in the Python API client generated by Swagger Codegen 3.x?

Tags: python, swagger, bearer-token, swagger-codegen

I've generated a Python client library for [this API](https://api-invest.tinkoff.ru/openapi/docs/swagger-ui/swagger.yaml) by using the online Swagger Codegen at https://generator.swagger.io/. The API uses Bearer authentication:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

paths:
  /sandbox/register:
    post:
      ...
      security:
        - sso_auth: []
      ...

components:
  securitySchemes:
    sso_auth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```

However, the `Configuration` class in generated Python client has no `access_token` field.

How to fill the Bearer access token when using the generated client library?

The codegen endpoint `POST /gen/clients/{language}` has the `authorizationValue` and `securityDefinition` parameters - do I need to configure these parameters somehow?

```json
"authorizationValue": {
  "value": "string",
  "type": "string",
  "keyName": "string"
},
"securityDefinition": {
  "type": "string",
  "description": "string"
}
```

Comment: Please post your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, since your API is OpenAPI 3.0 you need to use Swagger Codegen 3.x, i.e. https://generator3.swagger.io or `swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.11.jar`. The generator at https://generator.swagger.io is for OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`).

That said, there's a bug in the Python generator of Swagger Codegen 3.x, it doesn't generate the code for Bearer authentication in OpenAPI 3.0 definitions. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/issues

The `authorizationValue` and `securityDefinition` parameters of `/gen/clients` are not related to security definitions in OpenAPI files.

As a workaround, edit your OpenAPI YAML file and replace this part

```yaml
  securitySchemes:
    sso_auth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```

with:

```yaml
  securitySchemes:
    sso_auth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: Authorization
```

Then generate a new Python client from the modified API definition.

Now, once you have installed the client package as explained in `README.md`, you should be able to set the token as follows:

```python
import swagger_client
...

# Configure API key authorization: sso_auth
configuration = swagger_client.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['Authorization'] = 'YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN'
configuration.api_key_prefix['Authorization'] = 'Bearer'

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.MarketApi(swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration))
...
```

Comment: hey, do you know if thats still the case? thanks

Comment: this i found it: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/1577

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could simply set `access_token` of `Configuration` object like this:

```
configuration = Configuration()
configuration.verify_ssl = ...
configuration.host = ...
configuration.access_token = token
```

Information taken from here, schema generated by fastapi.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing that is to use the *bearer security scheme*, as follows:

**openapi-definition.json**

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  ...
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "bearerAuth": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer",
        "bearerFormat": "JWT"
      }
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {"bearerAuth":  []}
  ]
```

**Python Client**

```
import swagger_client
...

# Configure API authorization
configuration = swagger_client.Configuration()
configuration.access_token = 'YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN'

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.AnApi(swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration))
...
```

Tested with OpenApi 3.0.1

Documentation: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/